# Archiving without relative path

Tags: linux, tar, gunzip

On Linux (Ubuntu 18.04), Suppose I have the following directories tree:

```
 Week
   |  
   |
   -----Days
         |
         |
         -----Sunday
                |
                |
                -----file1.txt
                -----file2.txt
         -----Monday
                |
                |
                -----file1.txt
                -----file2.txt
```

If my current directory is `Days`, then taring with

`user@here:~/Week/Days$ tar -zcvf Sunday.tar.gz Sunday`
will produce `Sunday.tar.gz` in which there will be `Sunday` directory with `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`

**but** if I am in `Week` directory, then taring with

`user@here:~/Week$ tar -zcvf Sunday.tar.gz Days/Sunday`
will produce `Sunday.tar.gz` in which there will be `Days` directory and in it there will be `Sunday` directory with `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`

Is it possible to tar from `Week` and get the same hierarchy like in the first case? (i.e., without `Days` directory)

Comment: `tar -zcvf Sunday.tar.gz -C Days Sunday`

Comment: @kaylum - exactly what I have looked for! Thanks